# How to set an Id in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

When I have an entity object, how do I set the relationship without having the object, just by having the id? Something like:

```
Post.BlogId = 42
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marc is right for EF 4 (+1). But for EF 1 you can do:

```
Post.BlogReference.EntityKey = 
    new EntityKey("MyEntities.Blogs", "BlogId", 42);
```

Replace the strings with whatever is right for your model.

Comment: Thanks for your support, Craig!! Maybe all those downvoters will reconsider punishing my post.....

Answer (score 2):

You wait until Entity Framework v4 ships with .NET 4.0 :-)

This is one of the major features that EF4 will bring - the ability to set a relationship/association by using just the foreign key ID.

See:

- [Foreign Keys in Entity Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/efdesign/archive/2009/03/16/foreign-keys-in-the-entity-framework.aspx)
- [Foreign Key Relationship in the Entity Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2009/11/06/foreign-key-relationships-in-the-entity-framework.aspx)